# Form Validation is not functioning

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Hi i am a student learning form validations in Codeigniter i keep setting rules for my form but it is not working i do not understand where i am wrong.

**Controller**

```
    <?php
class Register extends CI_Controller {


public function index(){
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','First Name', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
     echo "Form validated";
    }
    $this->load->view('register');
}
}
?>
```

**View**

```
 <div class="signup-form">
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class= "alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>Register.php/Register/index" method="post">
<h2>Register</h2>
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "fname" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                <input onkeypress="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)" type="text" class="form-control" name="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name" required="required">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: what response you are getting after submitting this form?

Comment: action="<?php echo base_url()?>register/index" try this to your form action attribute.